# ERR_ABORTED 404 error for bootstrap.min.css in jsp page

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp

I am trying to build a crud application using Spring MVC, Hibernate, JSP. I was trying to include bootstrap in my JSP page. After inspecting my JSP page I got the following error in my console 
**http://localhost:8080/spring_hibernate/users/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404**
Here is my Project Structure

- spring_hibernate

  - src

    - main

      - resources

        - css

          - bootstrap.min.css

I have declared mvc resource mapping in **servlet.xml** file like this
`<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"></mvc:resources>`

I have used the following declaration in my jsp page for including bootstrap.min.css

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Users</title>
 <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head></html>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use following url for css stylesheet link in jsp file

```
<link href="resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: It is still giving the same error. Now by changing the link tag as mentioned above, it is fetching in wrong path http://localhost:8080/spring_hibernate/users/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: where jsp files are stored?. Please share the total project structure

Comment: I have solved this issue. Actually I was putting the js and CSS files in the wrong resources folder. Thanks for your help